# Beginner R and required to teach: Selecting a defined column using $

Tags: r, csv

I recently began using `R` with no prior coding experience after I was transferred to a new department and I want to understand how some `R` functions work. I have this written code:

```
read.csv("something.csv",header=TRUE)$DATE123
```

The csv file contains a time series with header that begins with `DATE` in `A1` cell.

How does `R` classify that `A` column is `DATE123`? is it because of the `header=true` and `$`?

Comment: `header =TRUE` means 1st row of your csv file is column names

Comment: Maybe you start with reading the R documentation and understanding the samples provided there...

Comment: Try `read.csv("something.csv",header=TRUE) -> data; data$DATE123`

Comment: As `?read.csv` indicates `header = TRUE` is the default so it does not have to be specified.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comments, `header=TRUE` indicates that the first row of your files are column names. Thus, every object in that row will be a column with that name. In your case, there is probably a field in the first row of your `csv` file that is called `DATE123`.

A data frame consists of rows and columns. Each column in the data frame can be accessed by the `$` sign. If the name of the data frame is `df` and one of the columns is named `DATE123`, then you can extract all data from that column by using the following command:

```
df$DATE123
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this 100% cleared it up for me.